# Excel VBA macro to scrub financial reports

Tags: excel, vba

I have to scrub financial reports containing sensitive data, but still keep the look, feel, and purpose of the report.  I'm looking to create a macro that would find all numeric data (non formula) and multiple it by a number (or ideally a random number) to change the value thus sanitizing it for consultants at my company to look at.

The script I've found so far is this.  It works to Clear all numeric data, leaving text and formulas.  Could someone help me modify this VBA code to multiple all numeric values by a number instead of deleting it?

```
For Each wks In Worksheets
    'ignore errors in case there is only formulas
    On Error Resume Next
    wks.Cells.SpecialCells (xlCellTypeConstants, 1).ClearContents
    wks.Cells.SpecialCells (xlCellTypeConstants, 4).ClearContents
    wks.Cells.SpecialCells (xlCellTypeConstants, 16).ClearContents

    On Error GoTo 0
Next
Set wks = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will multiply every number in the workbook by a 'different' random number between 1.2 and 3 but keep the formulas.  Using a different random number for each value will make it nearly impossible for someone to crack the "magic number".  For more ways of calculating random numbers see [this link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/randomnumbers.aspx)

```
Sub scrubNumbers()
    Dim rRange As Range, rCell As Range
    Dim wkw As Worksheet
    Dim randomNum As Double

    For Each wks In Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)

        For Each rCell In rRange
            randomNum = Rnd * (3 - 1.2) + 1.2
            rCell = rCell.Value * randomNum
        Next rCell
    Next
    Set wks = Nothing
End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help!  It seems like it is running through the sequence more than once though?  I tried this on my sheets and values in the millions would end up as trillions or more.

Comment: If it's only being called once, It should only run each cell once, but if your equations rely upon multiple previous values you'll see that kind of inflation.  Try changing the range of the random number to 0.1 to 1.9 thus equally straddling 1 and hopefully bringing the results back to reality.